# How to write on change function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to post request with body using javaScript ajax

How can i apply Onchange function on checkbox , date , and name and send this data to post request

for checkbox if checked then its value true and if unchecked its false

```
    <form onsubmit="sectionWork()">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputDate">Date</label>
            <input type="date" id="exampleInputDate" name="date">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" aria-placeholder="Enter Name"  name = "naming" class="form-control" id="naming" >
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Releasing</button>
    </form>
```

here is javascript

```
        const sectionWork= () => {
        
        let body = {
             Checkbox: null,
             Date: null,
             name: null
        }
        
        $.ajax(url,
            {
                type : 'post',
                data : body,
                success: function (response) {   // success callback function
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error: function (error) { // error callback
                    console.log(error)
                    $('#p').append('Error: ' + error);
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first piece of advice would be to assign the `onSubmit` in javascript using jquery, instead of in the html, so you would have this:

```
// html:
<form id="section-work">

// javascript
$('form#section-work').submit(function() {
   // code here
});
```

My second piece of advice would be to abuse the FormData class instead of manually creating your array to post:

```
// javascript
$('form#section-work').submit(function() {
   const formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postDataUrl,
        data: formData,
        ...
   });
});
```

When you use `FormData` like that, that's equivalent to posting an object where each key is the `name` property of your input, and the value is the value of your input.

So if you have these inputs in your form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test-checkbox" />
<input type="text" name="test-text" />
<input type="date" id="exampleInputDate" name="date" />
```

.. then the json you submit will look like

```
{
   'test-checkbox' : true, // true if it is checked, or maybe it says 'on', i'm not sure
   'test-text' : 'abcd', // or whatever they wrote in the text field
   'date' : '2020-09-29' // not exactly sure how a date input submits, but it's probably in text form, ISO8601
}
```

If you can, let the `FormData` class do the heavy lifting for you

---

last piece of advice: use Axios instead of jQuery.Ajax, because Axios use promises/async-await out of the box. This pattern is much better:

```
await axios.post(url, formData);
```

Comment: for using axios do i need to download first ?

Comment: axios can be installed the same way jquery is -- you can put it as part of your build process if you have one, or you can just include it in a `script` tag, at this url: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.20.0/dist/axios.min.js`

Comment: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You should add name attribute for all inputs. Then you can listen submit event of the form by adding an id to it. Add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent submit form by HTML then send AJAX. I did it with jQuery because you already used it.

```
<form id="form1">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" name="check">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputDate">Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="exampleInputDate" name="date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" aria-placeholder="Enter Name" name="naming" class="form-control" id="naming">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Releasing</button>
</form>
```

Then the JS part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: '<your-url>',
      method: 'POST',
      data: $('#form1').serialize()
    });
  });
});
```